# How to keep the volume the same in every file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to make it so that the volume doesn't revert back to normal when I switch to a different file. I think I can use global tag but I don't know how (I'm relatively new to coding)
CODE FOR THE VOLUME SLIDER:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Help</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Music Settings</h1>
    <h2>Control Volume</h2>
    <h2 id="back" onclick='location.href="menu.html";' class="thumbnail">Back</h2>
    <global>    <audio id="audio" autoplay loop>
    <source src="gamemusic.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<input id="vol-control" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="SetVolume(this.value)">

<script>
    function SetVolume(val)
    {
        var player = document.getElementById('audio');
        console.log('Before: ' + player.volume);
        player.volume = val / 100;
        console.log('After: ' + player.volume);
    }
</script>
    </global>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use local storage to save the data of your volume to a variable

```
function SetVolume(val)
{
    var player = document.getElementById('audio');
    player.volume = val / 100;
    localStorage.setItem("volume", player.volume);
}
```

and retrieve data from local storage to set the volumes of other files

```
var volume = localStorage.getItem("volume");
```

Hope it helps